# Automatic backup set in ubuntu for mysql database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cron

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In my `/etc/crontab` I added some script for my mysql database backup.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
 17 *  *   *   *  root  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
 25 6  *   *   *  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
 47 6  *   *   7  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
 52 6  1   *   *  root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )

# this is my custom script for database backup daily
15 2   *   *   *  root  /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root database_name > /home/backup_$(date +%Y%m%d).sql 
#
```

It worked perfectly when I ran it from terminal. It is supposed to backup my database everyday at *2:15 AM* but it isn't doing anything form crontab.

Comment: You need to give password with -p option to make the cron to run.

Comment: @balakrishnan I don't have password for my database and this command work from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and is generally related to the cron environment variables. As cron is not a shell user it has different environment variables from the console users. You can compare by running something like this with both cron and your user that works:

```
usr/bin/env | sort > /tmp/cronEnv.out
```

This will allow you to compare both outputs. If i have to bet it should be something like timezones, language or binaries it can not find due to PATH being different. 
Please post the cron log here as well just in case. depending on the dristro they can generally be found here:

```
/var/log/cron //could also be syslog or something else.
```

There is an article about that [here.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1011623)

Not related to your question directly: I also programmed [a backups](https://github.com/ChinaNetCloud/nc-backup-py) script for Mysql and other stuff, is still a work in progress, but could work for your env, just about 50 or 60 servers using it so far, but you could try it and ping me if need help.

Aside this could be other problems, but if the script works then the env should be different for some reason.